# How do I use ceres::CubicInterpolator with data not on a uniform grid

Tags: c++, eigen, ceres-solver

Ceres solver allows interpolation with a piecewise cubic hermite interpolant, which I'm trying to use to create a cubic interpolant for Eigen.

[This snippet from `ceres/examples`](https://github.com/ceres-solver/ceres-solver/blob/master/examples/sampled_function/sampled_function.cc) shows how to set up an interpolator. Adapting it to provide a toy example for my use case:

```cpp
const int kNumSamples = 4;
double x[kNumSamples];
x[0] = 12.5; x[1] = 13.9; x[2] = 14.0; x[3] = 21.4;

double values[kNumSamples];
for (int i = 0; i < kNumSamples; ++i) {
    values[i] = (x[i] - 4.5) * (x[i]- 4.5);
}

Grid1D<double> array(values, 0, kNumSamples);
CubicInterpolator<Grid1D<double> > interpolator(array);
```

Which I believe can be evaluated at a location between the given data points like:

```cpp
double x_interp = 1.5;
double y_interp;
double dydx_interp;
double yi = interpolator_.Evaluate(x_interp, &y_interp, &dydx_interp);
```

But the Grid1D object has no concept of what the x values are. It always assumes the data is on a regular grid, starting at some index (in this case 0) and containing `kNumSamples` (in this case 4) samples.

**The Question**

How can I make `Grid1D` aware of the actual input x locations? Alternatively, what mapping should I be doing to my `x_interp` values to get the right answer out?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CubicInterpolator cannot handle non-uniformly distributed data. You will have to use something like a cubic spline yourself to do that.

Comment: Have you come across any good ones in particular, Sameer? I've been looking around and finding a lot of slightly-broken librraries, and a lot of ridiculously heavyweight toolboxes which are GPL dependent ...

Comment: I do not know of a library that does this, but for 1d and 2d, I wrote some MATLAB code a long time ago, which should be relatively straight forward to convert to an automatically differentiated version.  

https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~sagarwal/spline-0.11.tgz

The full math comes from Jan Kybic's thesis, but for basic cubic splines and thin plate splines in two dimensions, life is fairly simple and straightforward.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have another dig around when I next come back to this project and will let you know if I end up reimplementing this.